# I'm trying to hide php extension in Ubuntu 16.04 apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In server and i created a file named as **.htaccess** in /var/www/html and then i added the following lines in that

```
 `Options +FollowSymLinks`
 `RewriteEngine On`
 `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
 `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
 `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`
```

and enabled mod_rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restarted the service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but also it is not working anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code helps you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```